# Find the number of all triplets (x, y, z) of positive integers such that 1/x + 1/y + 1/z = 1/2021.

Tags: number-theory, egyptian-fractions

1.Find the number of all triplets $(x, y, z)$ of positive integers such that
$$ \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{2021}.$$

2.How about if $x,y,z$ are odd?

What I did: we can get
$$xyz=2021(xy+yz+zx),$$
Since $2021=43\times  47$, then we can let $x=43s,y=47t\Rightarrow z=\dfrac {2021 s t}{s t - 43 s - 47 t}$.
But how can I find the $s,t$ such that $z\in\mathbb{N}$?

Here, I only care about the number of solutions  instead of caring what the specific solution is.

Comment: Could you please add the source of the problem? Problems pertaining to active math contests are [off-topic](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy) and the use of "2021" suggests this problem *might* be from a contest this year.

Comment: @André Armatowski, It is not contest problems. Use of 2021, just because 2021 only have two  non-trivial factor.

Comment: It is a special case of $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Why do you not just share the source?

Comment: A similar question came for me in a PRMO model, except that the last variable ($\frac{1}z$) was missing and $n = 2004$ or so...

Comment: There is no source @André Armatowski

Comment: Assume I didn't make any mistake. By brute force, the numbers for $(1)$ and $(2)$ are $13978$ and $2245$ respectively. If one impose an extra constraint $x \le y \le z$,the numbers reduce to $2339$ and $379$. These numbers are too large, it doesn't seem possible to work out all those $(x,y,z)$ by hand....

Answer (score 2):

The following sage code computes the list of all solutions, then counts their number. (One can finally easily extract from the list the solutions with only odd components.)

---

Let us search first the solutions with $x\ge y\ge z$.
The sum of the three positive real numbers $\frac1x$, $\frac1y$, $\frac1z$ is $\frac1{2021}$, so the biggest one is $\frac1z\ge \frac1{3\cdot 2021}$, so $z\le 3\cdot 2021$. For each possible integer $z$ with $2021< z\le 3\cdot 2021$ we compute the fraction
$$
\frac 1{2021}-\frac 1{z}=f=\frac ab\qquad
\text{ with }a, b\in\Bbb Z_{>0}\ ,\ (a,b)=1\ .
$$
Here, $a, b$ are relatively prime (natural) numbers.
Then we try to write $f=\frac ab$ in the form $\frac 1x+\frac 1y=\frac {x+y}{xy}=\frac ab$. This gives $axy=b(x+y)$,
so
$$
(ax-b)(ay-b)=a^2xy -abx -aby + b^2 = b^2\ .
$$
The integers $(ax-b)$ and $(ay-b)$ are (complementary) divisors of $b^2$. They cannot be both negative, since then $b^2=(ax-b)(ay-b)\le|ax-b|\; |ay-b|\le b\cdot b=b^2$, and for the equality we must have $x=y=0$. So they are nonzero natural numbers. To collect the relevant possibilities we let $d_x>0$ run over the divisors of $b^2$, consider $d_y=b^2/d_x$, and have to arrange that $(*)$ both $x=(b+d_x)/a$ and $y=(b+d_y)/a$ are in $\Bbb Z$. Recall that we started with $x\ge y$, so correspondingly $d_x\ge d_y$, i.e. $d_x^2\ge d_xd_y=b^2$, i.e. $d_x\ge b\ge d_y$. (The "coincidences" of values for $a,b$ with the condition $(*)$ above satisfied are no longer considered in a "theoretical" manner, we just let the engine decide in the finitely many cases what happens...)

The following code is self-explanatory. ([sage](https://www.sagemath.org) syntax is close to human language.)

```
solutions = []
N = 2021
for z in [N + 1 .. 3*N]:
    f = 1/N - 1/z
    new_solutions = []
    a, b = f.numerator(), f.denominator()
    dy_candidates = [dy for dy in (b^2).divisors() 
                     if dy <= b and (b + dy) % a == 0]
    for dy in dy_candidates:
        x, y = (b + b^2/dy)/a, (b + dy)/a
        new_solutions += list(set([(x, y, z), (y, z, x), (z, x, y),
                                   (x, z, y), (z, y, x), (y, x, z),]))
    if new_solutions:
        print(f'z = {z} :: # new solutions = {len(new_solutions)}')
        solutions += new_solutions

solutions = list(set(solutions))
solutions.sort()

different_solutions     = [(x, y, z) for (x, y, z) in solutions if x <= y and y <= z]
odd_solutions           = [(x, y, z) for (x, y, z) in solutions if x*y*z % 2]
different_odd_solutions = [sol for sol in odd_solutions if sol in different_solutions]

print(f'FOUND :: #               solutions = {len(          solutions)}')
print(f'FOUND :: # different     solutions = {len(different_solutions)}')
print(f'FOUND :: #           odd solutions = {len(odd_solutions)}')
print(f'FOUND :: # different odd solutions = {len(different_odd_solutions)}')
```

Well, it took some seconds to print the progress (and compute) the few solutions, here is the count of them... this was the question...

```
FOUND :: #               solutions = 13978
FOUND :: # different     solutions = 2339
FOUND :: #           odd solutions = 2245
FOUND :: # different odd solutions = 379
```

(In the "different solutions" we collect only triples $x,y,z$ with $x\le y\le z$.)

---

Example: Some random odd solution is...

```
sage: import random
sage: random.choice(different_odd_solutions)
(3225, 8385, 15275)
```

This was found as follows. In the $z$-loop, $z$ took the special value $3225$. (The other values are too big...) Then we compute the fraction
$$
f=\frac 1{2021}-\frac 1{3225}=\frac {28}{151575}\ ,
$$
and we use $a=28$, $b=151575=3 \cdot 5^{2} \cdot 43 \cdot 47$. There are $(2\cdot 1+1)(2\cdot 2+1)(2\cdot 1+1)(2\cdot 1+1) = 3^3\cdot 5=135$ divisors of $b^2$. Among them we consider only those $d_y\le b$ so that $d_y\equiv -b\pmod a$. Here they are:

```
sage: f = 1/N - 1/3225
sage: f
28/151575
sage: a, b = f.numerator(), f.denominator()
sage: a, b
(28, 151575)
sage: len((b^2).divisors())
135
sage: [dy for dy in (b^2).divisors() if dy <= b and (dy + b) % a == 0]
[45, 129, 18189, 83205]
```

For each such $d_y$ we compute the corresponding $d_x=b^2/d_y$, and compute $x=(b+d_x)/a$, $y=(b+d_y)/a$. The $y$-values found are...

```
sage: [(b + dy)/a for dy in (b^2).divisors() if dy <= b and (dy + b) % a == 0]
[5415, 5418, 6063, 8385]
```

And indeed, the $8385$ from the random solution we started with is in the list.

---

After sorting, the last few "different odd" solutions are:

```
sage: different_odd_solutions[-30:]
[(3423, 4935, 34589415),
 (3431, 9417, 10293),
 (3465, 4851, 16339785),
 (3483, 4815, 87580035),
 (3525, 4737, 79778975),
 (3573, 4653, 79431363),
 (3575, 4653, 5911425),
 (3591, 5719, 24111),
 (3619, 4577, 712259009),
 (3713, 4435, 708087665),
 (3835, 4277, 4173365),
 (3905, 4189, 465628295),
 (3913, 4277, 183911),
 (3927, 4165, 16339785),
 (3995, 4097, 2435305),
 (3995, 5405, 16813),
 (3999, 4089, 5450637),
 (3999, 4371, 62651),
 (4043, 4043, 8170903),
 (4085, 4085, 191995),
 (4085, 4465, 38399),
 (4089, 4089, 175827),
 (4257, 4653, 22231),
 (4277, 5719, 11609),
 (4389, 5719, 10857),
 (4515, 4935, 14147),
 (5719, 6251, 6251),
 (5805, 6063, 6345),
 (5891, 5891, 6439),
 (6063, 6063, 6063)]
```

Comment: As to the number of solutions see https://oeis.org/A227610

Answer (score 1):

It was necessary to write the solution in a more General form:

$$\frac{t}{q}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$

$t,q$ - integers.

Decomposing on the factors as follows: $p^2-s^2=(p-s)(p+s)=2qL$

The solutions have the form:

$$x=\frac{p(p-s)}{tL-q}$$

$$y=\frac{p(p+s)}{tL-q}$$

$$z=L$$

Decomposing on the factors as follows: $p^2-s^2=(p-s)(p+s)=qL$

The solutions have the form:

$$x=\frac{2p(p-s)}{tL-q}$$

$$y=\frac{2p(p+s)}{tL-q}$$

$$z=L$$